# Using Math With C++

Tags: c++, math

I am a Java developer and I'm just starting to teach myself c++ as well. I know some of the differences between Java and c++ but I'm not sure what is going on here. Here is the code I am having a problem with. Its just from a tutorial so I'm not worried about accuracy.

```
void calculateHourly() {
    float totalWeeklyWage = mFltHourlySalary * mIntHoursWorked;
    float totalSales = mIntCostOfShoe * mIntUnitsSold;
    float totalCommission = (mIntHourlyCommission / 100) * totalSales;
    float grandTotalWage = totalWeeklyWage + totalCommission;

    cout << "You will get $" << grandTotalWage << " for selling " << mIntUnitsSold << " shoes in a week."
        << endl;
}
```

The problem is the line

`float totalCommission = (mIntHourlyCommission / 100) * totalSales;`

For whatever reason `totalCommission = 0` when this method is done running. I have debugged this and all the other variables in this method equal what they are supposed to be equal to. With my Java cap on and the little knowledge I have of c++ tell me this should be working.

Am I missing something painfully simple in this method or is there a greater issue at hand? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that really a member function (method) and not a free function?

Comment: You're performing integer arithmetic.  The behavior would be the same in Java.

Comment: Ok I know what a member function is but what is a free function?

Comment: @JasonCrosby: A free function is one like you have in your example, i.e., not a member function of a class or struct.  A member function's definition would look like this; `void SomeType::foo() {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following uses integer division, the result of which is also integer:

```
mIntHourlyCommission / 100
```

Either cast `mIntHourlyCommission` to `float`, or turn `100` into a `float` literal: `100.0f`.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, shouldn't he use `100.0f`? Otherwise the compiler might complain about truncating a `double` to a `float`

Comment: Thanks for the help I changed 100 to 100.0 and it works just fine now. I tried to cast it before but I may have placed the cast in the wrong place. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm still a C++ noob. I was racking my brains today on why my math wasn't working. When I switched division by 100 to `100.0f`, you solved my problem. Now my little progress bar widget is working perfectly. Funny how answering someone else can help someone else on a completely different problem.

Answer (score 6):

The 100 is being cast as an int and rounded.

You'll need to use

```
 float totalCommission = (mIntHourlyCommission / 100.) * totalSales;
```

or

```
 float totalCommission = (mIntHourlyCommission / (float) 100) * totalSales;
```

instead to directly cast it into the right type.

Comment: Isn't the issue that `mIntHourlyCommission` is an integer? Otherwise 100 would be promoted to a float, no? I would do
`float totalCommission = (float)mIntHourlyCommission / 100.0f * totalSales;`

Comment: @slavik262: Yes, yes it is.  Was just typing that.

Comment: Its just an example I was working with to become familiar with c++. It's not meant to be extremely accurate or plan for every possible scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mIntHourlyCommission int and less than 100?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should never ever use floats for money. Use the largest int-type available for the smallest amount you are dealing with (eg long int for cent).